# Scrape table from static web site

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need scrape table with top level domains from [iana.org](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db).

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='tld-table')
```

How can I get this to pandas DataFrame with structure as it is on web site (DOMAIN, TYPE, TLD MANAGER).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas already comes with something to read tables [from html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), no need to use BeautifulSoup:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db"
# This returns a list of DataFrames with all tables in the page. 
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `pd.read_html`

```
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db"

df = pd.read_html(URL)[0]

print(df.head())
    Domain     Type                            TLD Manager
0     .aaa  generic  American Automobile Association, Inc.
1    .aarp  generic                                   AARP
2  .abarth  generic         Fiat Chrysler Automobiles N.V.
3     .abb  generic                                ABB Ltd
4  .abbott  generic              Abbott Laboratories, Inc.
```